# Using 'this' in a Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, indexing

Having some trouble getting 'this' to behave as I would expect it -

Basically, I have an object, and I am unable to access an array in the object from a function within the same object -

It looks like this:

```
var articles = {
    article : {
        1: {
            title : 'This is a Title',
            content : 'This is the content of the article'
        },
        2: {
            title : 'This is the second article',
            content : 'This is the second article content'   
        },
        3: {
            title : 'This is the third article',
            content : 'Making information transferrable. Identifiable. Manipulatable.'   
        }
    },
    numArticles : function(){
        var size = 0, key;
        for (key in this.article){
            if(this.article.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;               
        }
        return size;
    },
    buildInterface : function(){
        var aSize = this.numArticles();
        for(var i = 0; i < aSize; i++){
            $('body').append('<article><h2>' + this.article[i].title + '</h2></article>');               
        }
    }
}
```

the buildInterface() function is not able to access the 'article' array in this scenario.

Here is an example of this in progress:

http://jsfiddle.net/merk/xV2n6/41/

Any help here would be appreciated -

I have a hunch it may be a scoping issue - hopefully it is not something related to JSFiddle -

Thanks a ton -

Peace

Mark

Comment: @thatidiotguy it's the variable "articles" ...

Comment: @Pointy: I think that idiot meant "I don't see an array" :p j/k

Comment: @jAndy apologies for my idiocy. I do have the name though!

Comment: @thatidiotguy: haha yea, I was just making fun out of it, looked pretty much just like a typo

Comment: Perhaps `articles.article` should be a *real* array.

Comment: Also, since you're treating `article` as an array, why not make it an actual array? You'd get `length` for free, so you wouldn't need numArticles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have inconsistent indexing for your `article` variable: properties are defined beginning from `1`, yet you start from `0` in `buildArticles` method `for` loop. You can fix this with...

```
for(var i = 1; i <= aSize; i++){
  $('body').append('<article><h2>' + this.article[i].title + '</h2></article>');               
};
```

... or (and that's much better for my taste, as you're basically trying to use Object for the Array's work) rewrite the `article` definition into a proper Array:

```
article : [{
        title : 'This is a Title',
        content : 'This is the content of the article'
    }, {
    title : 'This is the second article',
    content : 'This is the second article content'   
    }, {
    title : 'This is the third article',
    content : 'Making information transferrable. Identifiable. Manipulatable.'   
    }],
...
```

... leaving your buildArticles `for` loop as it is now (as indexing now properly starts from 0).

BTW, this way you don't even have to make a special function to count your articles: `article.length` would be quite enough.

Here's [**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xV2n6/53/) with this approach's illustration.

---

As a sidenote, if you had actually checked the debugger, you would have noticed that it's `this.articles[0]` that is `undefined` (so trying to take `title` out of it is wrong), and not `this.articles`. Hence it's definitely not a question of scope.

Comment: Great suggestion on the proper Array tip - definitely gonna switch up to that -

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var articles = {
    article : {
        1: {
            title : 'This is a Title',
            content : 'This is the content of the article'
        },
        2: {
        title : 'This is the second article',
        content : 'This is the second article content'   
        },
        3: {
        title : 'This is the third article',
        content : 'Making information transferrable. Identifiable. Manipulatable.'   
        }
    },
    numArticles : function(){
        var size = 0, key;
        for (key in this.article){
            if(this.article.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;               
        }
        return size;
    },
    buildInterface : function(){
        var aSize = this.numArticles();
        for(var i = 1; i <= aSize; i++){
            console.log( '<article><h2>' + this.article[i]['title'] + '</h2></article>');               
        };
    }
}
```

The problem in your case, that you had started with the element on the zero position in your array. But you have no 0 element. So it will give you an error. And this is working as expected.